# Wait for table row change with click action on another button

Tags: cypress, do-while

I have to wait for a table row which takes 0 to n seconds to be displayed. To get the row displayed you have to click on a search button. I tried to do it by a do..while loop, but it was not possible.

Code used:

```js
let blnFound = false
do {
cy.get(pageCommonID.btnSearch(),{timeout: Cypress.env('GLOBAL_TIMEOUT_ms'),log: True}).scrollIntoView().click({force: true,multiple: true});                
cy.get(pageWorkloadCaseID.tblResult()).find('tr').then((rows) => {
    if (rows.length != 0) {
        blnFound = true
        return true
    } else {
        actualTime = new Date().getTime()
        cy.wait('BIT_GLOBAL_TIMEOUT_MEDIUM')
        let elapsedTime = actualTime - startTime
        console.log('info', strID, 'startTime: ' + startTime)
        console.log('info', strID, 'actualTime: ' + actualTime)
        console.log('info', strID, 'Case not found in Table. Waiting...\n
                               Elapsed Time: ' + (Math.ceil(elapsedTime / 1000)) / 60 + ' Min')
        if ((Math.ceil(elapsedTime / 1000)) / 60 >= 45) {
            console.log('info', strID, 'Case not found in Table. Waiting Time was bigger than 45Min')
            throw new Error('Case not found in Table. Waiting Time was 45Min\'')
        }
    }
})
console.log('blnFound out of Then: ' + blnFound)
    if (intCount >= 360) {
        // interrupt do While
        break;
    }
    intCount++
} while (!blnFound)`
```

The script does not interrupt because blnFound is always false.
How can I wait on the table row to be displayed when the time is not predefined and the reaction is only on a button click event?

The code snippet is part of the precondition of the test. It is not a test of the searching function. So, doing this precondition in a before or before each is not possible because of the missing timeout feature. So, the click and the next wait will only be done once until all timeouts are over.

I tried to use wrapping, aliases, shifting all to other functionalities, building submethods to encapsulate the relevant commands.

Comment: Why don't you just do `cy.get(pageWorkloadCaseID.tblResult()).find('tr')` and rely on cypress timeout to find it?

Comment: Because the tablerow will only change on click event on an additional button.
Just clicking and waiting is no solution because the table will never be updated by the application.
I have to click on the button to get the table updated.
And i have to do it without a predefined time.
It may be updated in the background in 1s or in 45 Minutes.
This isdepending on the infrastructure and reacting slots on other external systems.

Comment: No, do not mix up asynchronous commands `cy.find()` with synchronous code like `do...while`. Obviously you need to wait for the commands to set the found flag before using that flag.  Both the linked answers will do just that, if you study the patterns you will see they work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to invent your own testing framework, but in fact you can cut out a lot of muddle.

Here is an example, I've used id's for the search button and result table but you can substitute other selectors as needed.

The test is written on the basis that you've entered a search text that will produce some results. If you miss out that step, it's not really a test.

By defining expected results, the click will not need to be repeated - you can just allow Cypress to wait for results within the expected timeout.

```js
it('tests the search feature', {timeout:Cypress.env('GLOBAL_TIMEOUT_ms')}, ()=> {
  cy.get('input#search-input').type('search for me')
  cy.get('button#search-button').click()         
  cy.get('table#results tr')
    .its('length')
    .should('be.gt', 0)
})
```

Comment: I have not written the complete test with precondition and so on.
Because it is not relevant for this problem.
A simple waiting timeout after clicking once will never get a result. the table will never be filled automatically with out the click on the search button.This is because of the infrastructure in the backend. There are several external Systems which has different reacting times and different timeslots to react.
It may be that the Result is available in 1s or it takes about 45Minutes.
But the result, which is available will only be displayed by Clicking on the search button.